# How to draw rectangle in Qgraphicscene?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

[image]

I am trying to draw a rectangle in QGraphicscene to select the part of the QGraphicsitem.

I have tried the following code but is not working as i expected.It is not showing any error and expected result too

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QByteArray, QDataStream, QIODevice, QMimeData, QPointF, QPoint, Qt, QEvent, QCoreApplication,QRect,QSize,QSortFilterProxyModel,QRegExp)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QDrag, QPainter, QPixmap, QBrush,QCursor,QPolygon, QLinearGradient, QIcon, QPen, QPainterPath, QTransform,QStandardItem,QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene, QMainWindow, QAction,  QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter

class MyWidget(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scene=QGraphicsScene()
        self.setSceneRect(0,0,600,600)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
        self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.black))
        self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.targetForLine=QRect()
        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.target = self.TargPosForLine((event.pos()), "ForRect")#Geometry of rectangle
        qp=QPainter()
        qp.setPen(QColor(Qt.red))
        br = QBrush(QColor(Qt.red))
        qp.setBrush(br)
        qp.drawRect(QRect(self.target))
        # qp.drawRect(10,10,100,100)

        self.update()

    def TargPosForLine(self, position, mode):

        self.clicked_column = int((position.y() // 16)) * 16
        self.clicked_row = int((position.x() // 16)) * 16
        if self.clicked_column < 0:
            self.clicked_column = 0
        if self.clicked_row < 0:
            self.clicked_row = 0
        if (mode == "ForRect"):
            return QRect(self.clicked_row, self.clicked_column, 16, 16)


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()
    #
    # def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    #     self.scene.removeItem(qp)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: can you provide the current output of the script?

Comment: It is showing a window with black Qgraphicscene

Comment: @Python Do not reinvent the wheel, what you are trying to implement already exists and is called QRubberBand.

Comment: My expectation is different from Qrubberband.

Comment: @Python QRubberBand is a rectangle that is used for the selection that is the definition you give in your question, what is your expectation that differs from QRubberBand?

Comment: @Python Your QPainter does not paint at all because it has not been assigned a device but it is not necessary anyway since in QGraphicsView you should use QGraphicsRectItem, I have added a duplicate that shows how to add a rectangle.